# Timezone independent time at client side

Tags: javascript, html

I need to obtain the server time but I only have javascript to play with. I need the time from the NA and EU regions. Is there a way to obtain server time. OR is there a JS code snippet that can help me achieve the same?

Just to make things clear, I am not looking for UTC. I haev an application that will do something for the user at a certain time. The application will be used in NA and EU regions where there is a time difference. I need the time from the server. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jquery, i found [this](http://jamespfarrell.com/blog/real-server-time-jquery-plugin/98/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using UTC, so your users see a unified time instead of trying to display the server time.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getutcdate.asp

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way of determining the time from the server is to *ask it* !

Anything derived from the client's clock will be more prone to clock skew or other errors because client machines don't usually have decent synchronisation methods like NTPv3 that are typically deployed on servers.

A trivial CGI script (PHP, perl, whatever) on the server combined with an AJAX call to get the data would do the job nicely.

Comment: it should be trivial in any server side language that you have access to.

Comment: i meant, i dont have access to any server side languages. its just javascript and html :(

Comment: your requirements are unclear then.  How can the client possibly know what the server thinks its local time is?

Comment: It might be possible to use XMLHttpRequest() to fetch a file from server and inspect the "Date" HTTP header to figure out "local" time for the server (Date will be in UTC usually, though). It will be easier to trust end user clock (that is, get current time via JavaScript in UTC) and just apply suitable correction for the time zone.